# RenderPointerListener object was given an infinite size during layout

Tags: flutter, dart, rendering, drawer

I'm trying to use drawer with the body as ListView but when I try to click the drawer icon  it gives my that error so I considered that there is a problem with the drawer hight so i wraped the drawer widget with  size box of height but nothing changed

I tried to wrap the List View with a size box and give it fixed height but nothing changed

so is there any way to solve this

this the code of the bage

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart'; 
import 'package:sakani/constants.dart';
import 'package:sakani/models/picture_cat_model.dart';
import 'package:sakani/widgets/custom_drawer.dart';
import '../widgets/image_cards_builder.dart';

class PrevieView extends StatelessWidget {
  const PrevieView({
    super.key,
    required this.image,
  });
  static String id = 'Previeview';
  final PicCat image;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final List<String> type = image.type.split(',');
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          title: Text(type.first),
          elevation: 0,
          foregroundColor: Colors.black,
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        ),
        drawer: const CustomDrawer(),
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
          child:ListView(
        
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                  child: Stack(
                    children: [
                      SizedBox(
                        width: double.infinity,
                        child: ClipRRect(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(kPrimaryPadding),
                          child: Image.network(
                            image.image,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Positioned(
                          child: IconButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        icon: const ImageIcon(
                            AssetImage("assets/icons/dots.png")),
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ))
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    left: 10,
                  ),
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      const Expanded(
                        child: Text(
                          "more similar photos",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 20,
                            color: Colors.black,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      IconButton(
                          onPressed: () {},
                          icon: Icon(
                            Icons.favorite,
                            color: Colors.red[700],
                          ))
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                ImagesBuilder(type: type.first),
        
            ],
          ),
        
        ));
  }
}
```

and this is the drawer code

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sakani/constants.dart';

import '../views/general_page.dart';

class CustomDrawer extends StatelessWidget {
  const CustomDrawer({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      width: 200,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          DrawerHeader(
              child: Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            children: [
              const Spacer(
                flex: 100,
              ),
              const Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 60),
                child: Text(
                  kPrimaryAppName,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
                ),
              ),
              const Spacer(),
              IconButton(onPressed: () {}, icon: const Icon(Icons.light_mode)),
            ],
          )),
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
            child: const ListTile(
              title: Text("General"),
            ),
          ),
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                return const GeneralView(
                  type: "nature",
                );
              }));
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Bcoz you have added **Spacer()** in your **DrawerHeader** remove this spacer and use SizedBox(width: "your value") instead.

never use **Spacer()** in Row/Column without using Expanded

```
 DrawerHeader(
          child: Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        children: [
          const Spacer( //remove this 
            flex: 100,  
          ),
          const Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 60),
            child: Text(
              kPrimaryAppName,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
            ),
          ),
          const Spacer(), //remove this 
          IconButton(onPressed: () {}, icon: const Icon(Icons.light_mode)),
        ],
      ))
```

Comment: I removed the spacer widget but nothing change and the problem seems with hight not the width cause the emulator show a yellow part a the bottom of the drawer

Comment: the problem is the gesturedetector when i wrapped it with a size box the error gone i don't know why but it solved